# how to display variable value in asp.net which is set in Page_Load function

Tags: asp.net, variables, pageload

I have a variable which I get from database I want to output this variable in the aspx page in between the html.
I tried to make it public but it shows some error, how can I use a variable set in page load function in its aspx page?

Comment: what is the error you are getting? make sure you are getting value in the variable. By the way, you can use either hidden field or viewstate too.

Comment: sorry, I'm new to asp .net but can I use them if my html starts after page load function ?

Comment: if I write response.write it prints the value, the error is I thought I shd make the variable public so I wrote public before the variable to make it public then in Visual studio it says "expected ;"

Comment: @Coder  I'm trying to store value into the variable in page load function and I'm trying to output this variable using <% Response.Write(myvar); %>

Comment: You can use Response.Write right in the Page_Load method, just after you have initialized it

Comment: but it outputs the value before the html I wrote in the aspx code, I want to insert my value in the middle of the html I've written in aspx page, isn't this possible in asp.net ???

Comment: That's very simple task, simply add a label/literal control like `<asp:Label runat="server" id="lblA" />` at the desired position in markup .aspx file and in code-behind write `lblA.Text = myVar;` to set its value. Avoid using Response.Write, it simply writes to the form.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

### First way

You place a Literal control in the point you want to display the variable and then you set on PageLoad this value to the Literal Control

```
<asp:Literal runat="server" id="txtValueA" EnableViewState="false" />
```

and on code behind.

```
txtValueA.Text = "one of the basic";
```

This way you have also more control over what you try to render out.

### Second way

The other way is to make it public as you say and print it when the page render. This is a different way, but not a better one.

```
public string cMyValue = "some string here";
```

and on aspx page

```
<%=cMyValue%>
```

This way you get the parameter when the page renders at run time and send this in run time on the Client.
**If you try this way inside an updatepanel, then the update is fail** because the update panel can not read and render again the full page but only the code behind.

Try to avoid this way, and use it only when you really needed it because this make a call to the code the moment its try to render the page and change the page...

One idea to use this way is when you have some extra calculation that you like to make, you flush the content and then you call a function with extra time cost. For example.

```
<%
  Response.Flush();
  Response.Write(CallATimeConsumeFunctionThatReturnString());
%>
```

Comment: I dont want to use these controls because they add messy code to the html output, you're answer may be correct bt thats not what i wanted

Comment: when I can store a variable in page load function why cudnt I show it in my aspx page with response.write ?? Is it just me or its not possible in asp.net?

Comment: @pahnin Yes its possible, I have update the code, but even the html is a mess as you say, this is the correct way. Maybe you do not have use to it, but this is the correct for the way asp.net work.

Comment: There's is a typo, it should be _runat="server"_.

Comment: @Coder Sorry, I fix it, the VS has spoiled me and not make me remember some small details when I type them with out vs help.

Comment: Thanks I'm choosing the second option anyway. I dont want messy code, I want to work it like php

Comment: @pahnin I use on my code all the possible ways, depend what I am doing. In my first days of asp.net I use to use also the second way, but after UpdatePanels and other thinks start to fail, I switch it to the first, and only use the second for the reason I mention here.

Comment: @pahnin Why they fail you may ask, Ok, if you use asp Controls to render stuff, then the asp.net keep also other information and you have more control over. One good information that keep is a hash of the controls and if the user try to change the controls (hack) and make post back, this can capture from the code behind. Also the view state is very cool for some cases that you try to avoid fetching data on post back.

Comment: @Aristos I dont think I'm gonna change until I experience once :P ;) Anyway thankx for the answer asp .net is a mess for a php user

Comment: @pahnin php have a different way of thinking, old asp is in a way closer to php. I do not say that is good or not, php is very powerful, but asp.net have a little different idea of how render a page and the reason is that offer some advanced - one of them is the server cache of the page. So they render everything on a buffer on the code behind, then run the page with this changes...

Comment: ya everything has its own advantages, I'm trying to run my code similar to php because its easy for me debug or modify