# How to show a variable value in ASP.NET Web Forms?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I try to show variable value like this:

```
<% userTotalCount.ToString(); %>
```

But I understand that at the start the value is null, that's why I can't see anything on the page. Value of `userTotalCount` Variable sets later in `Page_Load()` event. How to show this value after it being set.

Comment: take a label control and then set label value on page load

Comment: @Amit Kumar, Thank you! Done! I took wrong way.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can set using label control . 
First take a label `control` , and then set the text to that `label` on `page load` event .

Answer (score 11):

The error is that you do not render the value. To render it on page use (note the first `<%=` )

```
<%= userTotalCount.ToString(); %>
```

this is a short cut for

```
<% Response.Write(userTotalCount); %>
```

The value is set on PageLoad, then come back to render there, so you have it, but you do not render it.

You can also read : [how to display variable value in asp.net which is set in Page_Load function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9975628/how-to-display-variable-value-in-asp-net-which-is-set-in-page-load-function/9975826#9975826)