# Button Click from JS after page reload only works does not work consistently

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I have an ASP.Net web app and a part I'm working on is made up three pages:

Main Page, Search User Page and Edit User Page.

The workflow is as follows:

- Login and go to the Main Page. (Works Fine!)
- Go to Search User Page and search for users based on some criteria. (Works Fine!)
- Click on a user on the search result table and go to the Edit User Page with the user info populated. (Works Fine!)
- Press a "Save and Go Back" button and go back to the search results. The expected behavior is for the search page to reload the search results (and hence if the user attributes are changed in a way that they do not meet the search criteria they are not displayed. *(This works Funky!)*

This is how the logic works:

In **EditUserInfo.aspx.cs** I have:

```
 public partial class EditUserInfo: basePage{

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {

    }

    protected void btnSaveAndGoBack_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        //Save/Update User Data
        Session["SearchAfterLoad"] = true;
        ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript("string".GetType(), "goBack", "<script type=\"\"text/javascript\"\" language=\"\"javascript\"\">window.history.go(-2);</script>");
    }
```

In **SearchUsersPage.aspx.cs** I have:

```
 public partial class SearchUsersPage: basePage{

    public string SearchAfterLoad{
        get {
            if (Session["SearchAfterLoad"] != null) { return Session["SearchAfterLoad"].ToString();}
            else { return String.Empty; }
            }
        }
    }

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {

    }
    protected void btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
         /*all the logic to use the UI elements to 
           search and populate the users in a table*/
         Session["SearchAfterLoad"] = false;
    }
```

in **SearchUsersPage.aspx** I have:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {

    var clickButton = document.getElementById("<%= btnSearch.ClientID %>");
    if ("<%=SearchAfterLoad%>" == "True") {
        clickButton.click();
    }
});
</script>
```

My issue is:
When debugging through Visual Studio (2019, 16.4.0), the logic works perfectly.  However! When I open the browser and navigate to my localhost (running on local iis) to test this, it will NOT click that search button and the search results do not get updated.

**Other observations:** 
This works fine on my colleague's PC with the same windows and the same VS fine no matter if we are debugging or just visiting the localhost. However it does not run when deployed to our test server.

It seems the first time we navigate to the search page, the **if statement** in the `document.ready()` function translates to:

```
if ("" == "True")
```

and never gets updated/re-rendered to `if("True" == "True")` when we go back to that page from the edit user page.

**P.S. `Session["SearchAfterLoad"]` is preserved and not lost when I move back and forth between the pages (but to be honest I have only verified it when in debug mode)**

Things That I have tried:

- In the `btnSaveAndGoBack_Click()` function called the URL directly by putting it into `Response.Redirect()` or by assigning it to `window.location.href` but then the search page is loaded fresh with no search criteria populated in its UI (just like visiting it the first time ever)
- Play with SessionStateServer and ASP.Net Session Manager, These dont have any effect.

---

**Looking forward:**

- Any good hint as to what the problem could be. Or,
- Or get the iis/ or whoever in charge to rebuild that page when we go back to it so I get my `if("True" == "True")` .
- For all other fool-proof ways to trigger that button click. Or,
- Any alternate way of going back and forth between the pages that
  saves me all the headache!

Comment: Are you trying to render JavaScript variable on a page server side (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25718089/how-to-show-a-variable-value-in-asp-net-web-forms)? It's somewhat unclear where you want "eval" to happen...

Comment: I'm trying to use a serverside variable in Javascript when the JS code is called. All of the answered questions that I have seen are about showing a serverside variable on the UI.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Im going to rewrite this question with the bigger picture.. stay tuned :)

Comment: AleX_ - so your question is "why my server restarts every request dropping our in-memory session state on production serves (even if we should never use in-memory session state outside dev)"? You really should stare at the question and narrow down the problem - it does not look like it has anything to do with rendering the script...

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Thanks for the tip but none of the session state modes (StateServer or In-memory) work for properly on my machine.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I did some research but I dont think my In-Proc Session State mode is the culprit.

Comment: I don't think I can help. "Works on one machine and does not on another" is really not a type of questions that can be answered on SO... You have to come up with [MCVE] and clear conditions when it fails to be answerable in SO format. So far I don't think the post is there... Generally just writing the question and coming with true [MCVE] would give you enough insight... (Side note: rendering button click from server side code is very strange thing to do - usually one would either redirect to desired page or at render desired page directly).

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov, Thanks for the feedback, I will try to modify the quesiton to meet the guidelines, but for the time being, I think you are right. ` Session["SearchAfterLoad"] = true;` does not seem to be working. I also tried ` Session["SearchAfterLoad"] = true.ToString();` but that one did not work either.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov OK my question is now how to redirect back after setting the session variable! I think I found my problem...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem in my code was calling go back right after assigning a session variable which caused the session variable to reset.